# Add options to a graph after construction

Tags: graphs-and-networks, options

Given a graph which has already been constructed, how can I add, e.g., the option `VertexSize -> 3` to that graph without having to deconstruct the graph?

Comment: Perhaps `Show["graph",VertexSize->3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add `newoptions` to a graph object `g`, you can use

1. [`Graph[g, newoptions]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)
2. [`Annotate[g, newoptions]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotate.html)
3. [`SetProperty[g, newoptions]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html)

**Examples:**

```
options = {VertexSize -> Large, PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled", VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red}};

SeedRandom[1];

Grid[Partition[#,2], Dividers -> All]&[Labeled[#, HoldForm @ #, Top] & /@
 {Unevaluated[rg = RandomGraph[{5, 9}, ImageSize -> 300]], 
  Unevaluated @ Graph[rg, options], 
  Unevaluated @ Annotate[rg, options],
  Unevaluated @ SetProperty[rg,  options]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a nice copy function that lets you keep it as a graph expression

[image]

Probably more efficient ways if you have assigned the graph or use the `%` output

However as mentioned in the comments you should be able to manipulate by pasting the graph expression in place of "graph"

```
Show["graph",VertexSize->3]
```

@Ulrich Neumann